# Find global minimum

Tags: calculus, optimization

for the course Non-Linear Optimization I faced the following problem I couldn't solve:

$x^2 + xy + 2y^2 + 3 \rightarrow min$ where $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$

Now I first computed the boundary points where $x,y$ $= \pm $ $\infty$

Both solutions gave $f(x,y)$ $ = \infty$

Now I don't know how to get the global minimum, do I have to take partial derivatives?

Please help!

Comment: You have to calculate the Hessian matrix of the function

Comment: Use Lagrange multipliers.

Answer (score 3):

Completing the square is your friend.

$$x^2+xy+2y^2+3=x^2+2x\frac{y}{2}+(\frac{y}{2})^2+\frac{7}{4}y^2+3=(x+\frac{y}{2})^2+\frac{7}{4}y^2+3\ge 3$$

Comment: Can you please be more precise, I am completely new to this subject

Comment: "Completing the square" means summing and subtracting to your expression other monomials, in order to be able to identify something as the square of a polynomial. Since squares are non-negative, this should help you.

As a trivial example of square completion, notice that $x^2 + 2x = x^2 + 2x + 1 - 1 = (x+1)^2 -1 \geq -1$.

Answer (score 1):

$$x^2 + xy + 2y^2 + 3 = x^2 + y^2 + xy + 3 + y^2 = (x + y)^2 - xy + 3 + y^2 + x^2 - x^2 - xy + xy$$

$$ = (x+y)^2 + (x-y)^2 + 3 + xy - x^2 \geq ......$$

Comment: This is going to be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, you are asked to find the minimum value of a function F[x,y]. Then, at any extremum (if several exist), the derivatives dF/dx and dF/dy must be zero. This leads to two equations for two unknowns, x and y. In your case, it is quite simple. Are you able to continue from here ?